# Why are new editors discouraged & not given an opportunity to explain/defend?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, new-users

I attempted to edit the following 'accepted' answer:

- [Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2395891/1327508) to "[Global javascript exception handler (in Chrome)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384666/global-javascript-exception-handler-in-chrome/53852089)"

... my purpose to editing it, was that as the 'accepted' answer, it's going to be the most viewed answer & as a consequence the fact that it starts with information that's not true (*the first line*) is not 'accurate/current' (*but maybe still valuable for historic reference, hence a strike-through & not a deletion*); in addition as a consumer of the answer, the most important part was the update (*to now being supported*) so I bolded that to make it `more accessible`, as well as correct two spelling errors (*technically one spelling error the first time & two the second edit.*)

I am explaining this in more detail here, because in both attempts to make the edits, apparently my abridged/truncated language wasn't significant to have the edit accepted because of the limited field length of an [Edit Summary]; which was frustrating enough.

The first time I submitted my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21730219), I was rejected 1 to 2 ... where [t3chb0t w 6.5kRep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235671/t3chb0t) approved; but [@Wizhi w 3.3kRep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4552529/wizhi) & [@silwar w 3.7kRep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557157/silwar) both rejected with what appeared as a "canned" answer:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
>   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
>   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

... really? not `even a little bit` ... honestly, I don't believe either of them actually took the time to read what I edited nor what I wrote in the [Edit Summary].  I think it would be interesting for the moderators to review @Wizhi & @silwar's edit rejections & see how many times they've used that "canned response".  As a new editor who took the time to edit & then try to complete the [Edit Summary] as best as possible, really demoralizing.

I didn't see any way to reply and/or appeal and/or retry, but I certainly wasn't happy with a canned rejection, especially when the canned rejection didn't even seem to apply (*especially in hindsight of the two "new" approved edits #5 & #6, discussed below*); so I tried again & really tried to explain as best as possible in my [new [Edit Summary]](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21731481).

Again, the result was 1 to 2 against.  [Yaakov Ainspan w 2.5kRep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4633197/yaakov-ainspan) approved; but at least this time I don't believe I received canned answers...

1. [Nick A w 4.2kRep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3270037/nick-a) wrote :: "If it was already rejected, why would you try to suggest it again?" ... maybe he didn't read my updated [Edit Summary] and I wonder why he asked me a question that I can't respond to.?.
2. [Community (*a bot? rotating admin account?*)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) wrote :: "This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed." ... the first line is factually incorrect, how is that not a critical issue?  I did look at the revision history, where is this 'see what should have been changed' you speak of, certainly not the canned response.
3. [Stephen Kennedy w 3kRep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397817/stephen-kennedy) didn't write anything, but instead "Reject and Edited" the answer ... so as new editor, I looked to see what he did ([revision #5](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2395891/revisions)), & he fixed the two spelling typos.  Fixing two spelling typos apparently rises to the standard of ::

   > This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read,
   >   easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either
   >   completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
   >   ... yet what I did didn't rise to this standard, huh?

When I saw that I also saw [revision #6](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2395891/revisions) by [TylerH w 15.3kRep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh) ... this is interesting, it pretty much looks exactly like the changes I made twice that were rejected both times.  I mean he did move the word 'Google', capitalized 'Now', and added 2013; but other than that when you combine edits 5 & 6, it pretty much looks like my edit.  And had any of the rejectors told me I needed to move the word 'Google', capitalize 'Now', and add 2013 to make my edit not be considered `completely superfluous`, I would have done that ... but somehow I missed 'seeing what should have been changed'.

So as a new editor, what's my takeaway?...  don't make edits until I have a 15kRep because then you don't have to deal with the limited [Edit Summary] field or have your changes be rejected for no reason.

To the admins I ask, with the above information in mind ::

- Why are new editors discouraged?
- Why are editors not given an opportunity to explain/defend/correct/update their edits?
- Upon rejection, why does the system not show the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) on disputing edits

... ironically, I did essentially get my edit, I just didn't get credit for it.

Comment: The [FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) contains instructions on what to do if you believe one of your edit suggestions was incorrectly rejected.

Comment: nice documented question. But you could have edited 20 other posts instead of writing it.

Comment: FYI you need 2k rep to edit posts without review, not 15k.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why would I edit anything if it's just going to be rejected for unclear reasons or you're forced to fight for it, and then have users who can edit then make your changes...  nothing changes unless people speak up.

Comment: how many times did that happen to you? aren't you generalizing for just one time? try again. A lot of edits are accepted. Gain more experience on the site by answering too.

Comment: @Servy I know that now, I read the link from gparyani ... that link would have been more helpful than any of the feedback given from any of the editing approvers gave above.

Comment: @George2.0Hope They're just doing their job.  If you think that the FAQ on disputing edits should be shown on every rejected edit (or certain ones, via some sort of criteria), the system should be doing that, not every reviewer in every rejection message.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I run many volunteer groups...  all it takes is a bad "first experience" to turn off people from the group for good...  I use SO, and I feel it's better the more people who contribute & make it accurate.  SO will lose people if they have my experience.

Comment: @Servy I agree it should show the FAQ, I'll amend my question.  I do think though that the 'process' should somehow be addressed.  Because in my case there is certainly disagreement on whether or not my edits were valid...  and in the end, apparently they were valid edits since that's the way the answer is now listed.

Comment: See the [chat conversation between Nick A and me](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44884867#44884867) about this. I felt as a single change the strikethrough was a valuable piece of historical context (if there were multiple revisions listed then I tend to agree with the approach Servy lists in his answer -- keep that for the post revision. In this case, there is just one adjustment and it seems better to reflect all states of the answer at first glance for multiple reasons [transparency and also the revision history is not obviously accessible to new users])

Comment: In that chat conversation, Nick A eventually agreed that the edit was done for the right reasons, e.g. you identified an answer that needed a change. The disagreement was simply in what way you agreed to change it (in other words, a disagreement over the color of the proverbial bikeshed). Therefore, the users who rejected the edit, including the user who rejected and edited without making the most critical change, were in the wrong. I could not retroactively approve your edit, so I did what I thought (and still think) appropriate -- edit the answer to include your change myself.

Comment: TylerH thank you very much, it's very enlightening, and as I commented to Jean-FrançoisFabre then I'll try to find where to submit to change that option to not only make it not harsh, but also to both list the FAQ & allow the reviewer to put a comment/suggestion @Servy 's suggestions, or the chat where the strikethrough is the issue, and/or the FAQ would have both been more encouraging than the way it is now.

Comment: It's unnecessary to list specific people and their reputation when asking about things like this. Combined with your foregone conclusion that people rejecting edits are trying to discourage defenseless new users, I think it reads as if you're trying to call them out publicly for inappropriate behavior. I don't know if you really intended it that way, but I think it gives that impression. You could describe what happened just as well without naming anyone.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I hear what your saying, my intent wasn't so much to call them out, but to illustrate with a specific occurance how confusing it is to someone new / low rep...  I do see your point, and I didn't do it capriciously.  In addition, since the info is publicly available on SO, I simply wanted to make it easy to have the info without people having to follow the links to understand where I was coming from... as TylerH did in his comment about NickA, in this regard the specifics really contributed to a better understanding.

Comment: @George As TylerH has said, I did read the comment that you provided and we had a fair discussion about it with the final agreement that the changes were suggested for the right reasons, I just wasn't a fan of the way that they had been done. Perhaps my response was a bit tongue in cheek (sorry about that!) and a cop-out instead of providing a real response but ultimately the reason was because I agreed with the previous reject reviewers in that it wasn't a good edit. Servy's answers covers my thoughts well regarding the strike through, In fact they even edited the post exactly as I would've.

Comment: @NickA No, you can't ping the reviewer of a suggested edit in comments.  You can ping an editor in comments, but not the reviewer of an edit.

Comment: @Servy Boo, fair enough

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As for your specific edit, I'd say you did a good job of identifying a problem with a post, but not a very good job of fixing it.

Striking through text in a post that's referring to an older version (or content that's less likely to be useful to readers) isn't really appropriate.  That's just...not really how edits work.  Edits of a post shouldn't make it look like a giant revision list of that post (that's what the actual revision list is for), they should make it look like the post was just written the way it's currently written.  If there are updates, you don't stick "**Update:**" in there, you add the updates.

In this specific case, where there is information about different versions, it's appropriate to mention *as if the post was being written that way in an original revision*, what the different versions of the product do.  So say, "In version Y the Baz Frobs the Foo."

You're also right that the behavior of a 5 year old version isn't the most important information in that answer that most readers are likely to want to see.  They're more likely to want to see the current behavior than what it was 5 years ago (even though the behavior 5 years ago will be relevant to some, and so should be included).  The solution to that isn't to strike it through, it's to *reorder the content*.  Open with the important information.  Include the historical context, or information for people forced into using very old versions, later.

I've edited the post to account for these things, see the revisions of that post to see what this looks like for the post in question.

---

As for the commentary on the actual edit process, and not just this one edit:

> Why are new editors discouraged?

Part of the problem here is simply that *good editing is hard*.  Yes, there's lots of useful information out there on good editing (both for English in general, and specific guidelines for our site), but in fact there's *so* much out there, that people can't read it all.  They just start editing.  And then they make mistakes, because they didn't read the guidelines.  I don't have good solution to this problem.  I can only throw my hands up and say that editing is hard and as a result there will be some friction when people start getting into it.  That's discouraging for plenty of people.

Another consequence of "editing is hard" is that reviewing is hard.  This means both that sometimes reviewers will get it wrong, even when doing their best, and also that it's *a lot of work*, which means that some people just won't put in the work needed, and also that in order to ensure edits actually get reviewed we can only expect so much work.  This is why, for example, you see canned responses for most all rejection reasons.  It's just too much work to have reviewers hand writing detailed custom responses (like the top half of this meta post here) for every single rejected edit.  There's just not enough time to do it.  Edits just wouldn't get reviewed if this was expected of all reviewers.  In order to have suggested edits at all, some compromises *need* to be made.

> Why are editors not given an opportunity to explain/defend/correct/update their edits?

You can explain your edit in the revision notes.  You can correct/update your edit by submitting future edits.  (Although I *strongly* suggest adjusting your edit to account for the feedback you got on why the edit was rejected before resubmitting.)  As for defending it, you can post on meta if you feel that a full blown conversation is needed about a given edit.  Yes, there's a bit of friction there.  That's because reviewing tons of edits a day is enough work as it is, spending tons of time discussing every edit that gets rejected (if it was made much easier to appeal edits) would potentially end up taking more time than the value added by the good edits.  People who feel strongly enough to start a full discussion on the topic can discuss it.  This limits the number to a manageable amount, and also ensures that people posting about it really care enough to learn, making it more likely to be worth our time to answer them.

Answer (score 4):

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Yes this is a canned comment/reply. Don't feel offended by that. Check the "reject edit" window that you'll see if you keep working on the site. You can add a custom comment only if the edit is harmful, not if in the "no improvement" case.

[image]

> Why are new editors discouraged & not given an opportunity to explain/defend?

You can flag for moderation. But why bothering for one edit? New editors are actually *encouraged* by 2 rep points. I know people who got 1000 rep just by editing (and edit getting accepted), not a single question or answer. Lots of work, and reward.

Very few sites allow newcomers to change content, so it's normal that there's a review process until you get 2000 rep (when reaching 2000 rep or after 1000 rep gain, the 2 points aren't awarded anymore, BTW)

Also, editing answers is often more difficult than editing *questions*. Personally I rarely edit answers, I prefer commenting (unless my expertise allows to do so without risking to deface the post). But I edit a lot of questions, and a lot of questions are from newcomers and lack proper formatting, have "thanks in advanced" stuff like that: easy & probably accepted-to-be edits. Try it.

TL;DR: your edit was rejected. Move on, find other posts to edit, there are plenty of them, and hone your skills in the meanwhile.

Comment: I must respectfully disagree.  No where on the review (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21730219) page does it allow you to flag for moderation.  Also, in my previous comment I explained why...  it shuts down new editors.  Also, if you think I did this for two points, you're mistaken; I care about the community & I always champion newcomers in all the organizations I'm a part of.  Finally, I think edit reviewers using canned responses that don't apply is good for the community.

Comment: @George2.0Hope Jean wasn't saying that you were doing it for the reputation, but rather that the fact that reputation is given for edits is evidence that SO is trying to encourage, not discourage, editing.

Comment: you can flag the post itself with a custom mod flag. But I doubt that it will be successful.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why suggest in your answer that you can "flag for moderation", but then in your comment say you "doubt that it would be successful"?

Comment: I think the mods will disregard that. Too many more important things to investigate. Unless you can prove that the same users always reject _your_ edits and it's directed to you.

Comment: @George2.0Hope edited answer to add the "reject edit" window. See that reviewers had no choice but the canned comment in your case.

Comment: Jean-FrançoisFabre then I'll try to find where to submit to change that option to not only make it not harsh, but also to both list the FAQ & allow the reviewer to put a comment/suggestion @Servy 's suggestions and/or the FAQ would have both been more encouraging than the way it is now.

Comment: feature request? well, good luck with that ... sincerely.

Comment: FYI the rep stops when you have hit 1k rep gained from suggested edits, not when you hit 2k total rep (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). It is just that most people stop gaining rep from them at 2k because that's when you lose the ability to make suggested edits, and they just start going through. In other words, if you have 1995 rep, and a pending suggested edit, and then you get an upvote on an answer and are at 2005 rep, then the next day your pending suggested edit gets approved, you would still get 2 reputation assuming you have not yet hit the 1k rep-gained limit.

Comment: Re *"the 2 points aren't awarded anymore"*: I am not sure what happens between 1,000 and 2,000, but above 2,000 reputation points, but below 5,000 reputation points (for the privilege *review of suggested edits to tag wikis*), 2 reputation points are still awarded for approved ***tag wiki*** edits (and review is no longer required above 20,000 reputation points). (Ref.: *[What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292)* - though somewhat cryptic, with most information in footnotes.)